# Excel VBA: Combine dates that are spaced out into a seperate sheet

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to take data that is randomly spaced out in a column and combine it into another sheet. The data that I am trying to move is an excel serial number and so I can not use `isEmpty() = False` or `.Value > 1` in my if statement. April 11th is an arbitrary date that all the other dates come after.  The problem is in my if statement. Been stuck on this for a while.

So far I have the following code:

```
EndRow = Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 1

For e = 27 To EndRow

If Cells(e, 22).Value > DateValue("April 19, 2011") Then

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V" & e).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    i = i + 1

End If
Next e
```

In the photo it shows the data I am working with.  I am trying to calculate the time it takes to empty a bin.  A "1" signifies the bin is running a "0" signifies it is not.  Whenever there is a 0 then a 1 (a start) in the cell beneath it, the timestamp is given.  Same for 0 then a 1 (a Stop).

[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgisV.png)

Comment: So what's wrong with your existing code, are you getting an error? Is nothing pasting over? Can you provide us some sample data (or show us how your dates are being formatted)? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I am not getting an error, it is just not filling any cells in "Sheet3" under the right conditions it will work when I use `isEmpty(Range("V" & e)) = True`, but it will also paste over the blank cells putting me back where I started.  The dates are formatted like 7/11/2018 1:29PM in the C column (Where the excel serial number is coming from).  These dates are from a SQL server and come with the data about the bins.

Comment: It looks like you need to increment `i` even if your `If` statement doesn't return `True`.

Comment: The paste destination is dependent on `i`, so iterating `i` would not paste the values together, i.e. stacked in the same column.  I tried you solution and it did not work.  Thank you though!

Comment: It looks like your dateserials are in multiple columns, but you're only checking column V?  Are your dateserials in column V?  The screenshot doesn't include column letters, so can't validate.

Comment: @BenGribbin Maybe I'm just not understanding what you're trying to do - but like tigeravatar said, if your dates are in multiple columns then you need to loop through the entire range, instead of just one column. Something like `For Each cell in Range("V2:Z" & EndRow)`...

Comment: It would help if your screenshot included the rows and columns to try to match with what you're doing.

Comment: @dwirony I am just trying to do one column at a time so I can get down a proof o f concept, but you are right; my range is 7 columns wide that I am trying to repeat this process on.  However, the problem is not being able to compare times in my if statement or use isEmpty().  I think something may be wrong with the way the data is formatted.

Comment: Also I updated the picture to give you guys more context.

Comment: Have you tried if (IsNumeric(Cells (e, 22) and Cells(e, 22).Value > DateValue("April 19, 2011"))?

Comment: Tried it, and each part of the `if` and it did not work.